# react component not taking full height of screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have created an Index component in Index.js which consists of a navbar and a landing page type design where i want 40% width as showcase section and the remaining 60% section to contain a react-bootstrap carousel and i want this Index component to take up 100% of screen height and for  the index_body contents to be displayed in the center and take full height of screen but my index_body takes height only of its content as seen in this screenshot there's some white space under the index_body: [image: open in new tab for visibility]
But when the bootstrap-carousel moves to other slide with bigger image the index_body becomes of height greater than 100% as shown : [image]

```
function Index() {
   return (
    <>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
        <div className="container">
            <Link to={'/'}className="navbar-brand logo"><h2>XYZ</h2></Link>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li><Link to={'/login'} className='btn btn-dark '>Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/signup'} className='btn btn-dark' style={mystyle}>Sign Up</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div className='index_body p-4 d-flex' > 
            <div className="info p-2 d-flex align-items-center" style={{width: '40%'}}>
                <div>
                <h1 className="info_heading">Showcase section </h1>
                <p className="info_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis perferendis mollitia nobis labore quasi reiciendis laboriosam aliquid ea eos perspiciatis.</p>

                <Link to={'/login'} className="btn btn-dark" style={mystyle}>Explore Now</Link>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} style={{width: '60%'}}>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="d-block w-100" src={firstSlide} alt="First slide" />
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641752084801-80dc709cdf28?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="Second slide" />
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641586822453-e2e5238fa075?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="Third slide" />
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
    </div>
    </>
```

I have already tried:

- to set index_body height: 100%
- set index_body min-height: 100%

Comment: Do you want 100% of body or 100% of viewport? If you mean 100% viewport, try to use 100vh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mdn,

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
> generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
> block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
> height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
> computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
> to the initial containing block.

Using height: 100vh; will take the full-page height as you are expecting.

But if you want `index_body` to take the height remaining after `navbar`, you can do something like below.

```
<>
   <nav className="navbar"></nav>
   <div className="index_body"> </div>
</>
```

Styles

```
.navbar {
   height: 100px; //example
}
.index_body {
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```